# Nested transactions not supported JasperReports exception in server works fine in localhost

Tags: mysql, hibernate, glassfish, jasper-reports

I have to continue the development of a web application done in JSF. It generates a PDF file using Jasper Reports. It works well in localhost, no warnings, no errors, everything is ok. But, when I uploaded to the VPS, it doesn't workm which is quite weird because the code is the same. My PC is an Ubuntu 15.04 with Glassfish 4.1 and Oracle Java 8. The server has an Ubuntu 14.04 server, Glassfish 4.1 and Oracle Java 7.
According to the log file of the glassfish of the server, there is a problem with the database but I don't know why. Localhost and server uses the same version of MySQL and the definition of the database is the same. Actually, I can login in the server, so I can access to the database.

**Is there any configuration which must be different in the server?**
Does anybody know what I should look for?

These are the errors:

ERROR 1

> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException:
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException:  Error creating scriptlet
>   class instance : com.appglass.jasper.CorteScriptlet
>   javax.el.ELException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException:
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException:   Error creating scriptlet
>   class instance : com.appglass.jasper.CorteScriptlet at
>   com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:293) at
>   com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
>   at
>   org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
>   at
>   org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
>   at
>   javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:149)
>   at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
>   at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:813)
>   at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300) at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
>   at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
>   at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
>   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
>   at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646) at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
>   at
>   org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:70)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
>   at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99) at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
>   at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
>   at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException:
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException:   Error creating scriptlet
>   class instance : com.appglass.jasper.CorteScriptlet at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.prepare(JRFillSubreport.java:762)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.prepareElements(JRFillElementContainer.java:328)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:377)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:351)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2039)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:771)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:281)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:144)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:909)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:822)
>   at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:61) at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:446)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:407)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:824)
>   at com.appglass.jasper.Reportes.crearPDF(Reportes.java:321) at
>   com.appglass.backing.ProyectoAgregadoBacking.crearPDF(ProyectoAgregadoBacking.java:99)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at
>   com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289) ... 46 more
>   Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error creating
>   scriptlet class instance : com.appglass.jasper.CorteScriptlet at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.scriptlets.DefaultScriptletFactory.getScriptlet(DefaultScriptletFactory.java:118)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.scriptlets.DefaultScriptletFactory.getScriplets(DefaultScriptletFactory.java:69)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createScriptlets(JRFillDataset.java:502)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.setParameterValues(JRFillDataset.java:619)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.setParameters(JRBaseFiller.java:1252)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:877)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:822)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.fillSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:652)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRSubreportRunnable.run(JRSubreportRunnable.java:59)
>   at
>   org.apache.commons.javaflow.bytecode.StackRecorder.execute(StackRecorder.java:95)
>   at
>   org.apache.commons.javaflow.Continuation.continueWith(Continuation.java:170)
>   at
>   org.apache.commons.javaflow.Continuation.startWith(Continuation.java:129)
>   at
>   org.apache.commons.javaflow.Continuation.startWith(Continuation.java:102)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRContinuationSubreportRunner.start(JRContinuationSubreportRunner.java:53)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.prepare(JRFillSubreport.java:737)
>   ... 66 more Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: nested
>   transactions not supported at
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:154)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1431)
>   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor475.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at
>   org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:356)
>   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy208.beginTransaction(Unknown Source) at
>   com.appglass.data.dao.ConstantesDAO.cargarConstantes(ConstantesDAO.java:32)
>   at com.appglass.jasper.CorteScriptlet.(CorteScriptlet.java:17)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:383) at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.scriptlets.DefaultScriptletFactory.getScriptlet(DefaultScriptletFactory.java:110)
>   ... 80 more

ERROR 2

> StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet
>   Faces Servlet threw exception org.hibernate.TransactionException:
>   nested transactions not supported at
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:154)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1431)
>   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor475.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at
>   org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:356)
>   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy208.beginTransaction(Unknown Source) at
>   com.appglass.data.dao.ConstantesDAO.cargarConstantes(ConstantesDAO.java:32)
>   at com.appglass.jasper.CorteScriptlet.(CorteScriptlet.java:17)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:383) at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.scriptlets.DefaultScriptletFactory.getScriptlet(DefaultScriptletFactory.java:110)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.scriptlets.DefaultScriptletFactory.getScriplets(DefaultScriptletFactory.java:69)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createScriptlets(JRFillDataset.java:502)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.setParameterValues(JRFillDataset.java:619)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.setParameters(JRBaseFiller.java:1252)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:877)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:822)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.fillSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:652)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRSubreportRunnable.run(JRSubreportRunnable.java:59)
>   at
>   org.apache.commons.javaflow.bytecode.StackRecorder.execute(StackRecorder.java:95)
>   at
>   org.apache.commons.javaflow.Continuation.continueWith(Continuation.java:170)
>   at
>   org.apache.commons.javaflow.Continuation.startWith(Continuation.java:129)
>   at
>   org.apache.commons.javaflow.Continuation.startWith(Continuation.java:102)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRContinuationSubreportRunner.start(JRContinuationSubreportRunner.java:53)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.prepare(JRFillSubreport.java:737)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.prepareElements(JRFillElementContainer.java:328)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:377)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:351)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2039)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:771)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:281)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:144)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:909)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:822)
>   at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:61) at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:446)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:407)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:824)
>   at com.appglass.jasper.Reportes.crearPDF(Reportes.java:321) at
>   com.appglass.backing.ProyectoAgregadoBacking.crearPDF(ProyectoAgregadoBacking.java:99)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at
>   com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289) at
>   com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
>   at
>   org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
>   at
>   org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
>   at
>   javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:149)
>   at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
>   more things

ProyectoAgregadoBacking

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ProyectoAgregadoBacking implements Serializable{
    public void crearPDF()
    {
        renderNotificationBar = false;
        Reportes reporte = new Reportes();
        Locale loc = null;
        disabledVerPDF = true;

        if(idIdioma == null){
            try{
                reporte.crearPDF(idProyecto, getCurrentUser(), getCurrentUser().getEmail(), false, null);
            } catch(SQLException sqlE){
                sqlE.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            if(idIdioma == 0){
                loc = new Locale("es", "ES");
            } else if(idIdioma == 1){
                loc = new Locale("en", "US");
            } else if(idIdioma == 2){
                loc = new Locale("it", "IT");
            } else if(idIdioma == 3){
                loc = new Locale("fr", "FR");
            } else if(idIdioma == 4){
                loc = new Locale("pt", "PT");
            } else if(idIdioma == 5){
                loc = new Locale("ru", "RU");
            } else if(idIdioma == 6){
                loc = new Locale("pl", "PL");
            }
            try {
                reporte.crearPDF(idProyecto, getCurrentUser(), getCurrentUser().getEmail(), false, loc);
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ProyectoAgregadoBacking.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }


            //Si el usuario es administrador: Reduce el stock
        if(getCurrentUser().getRol().compareTo("0") == 0){
            fabricar();
        }    

    }


}
```

Reporte.java

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class Reportes
{
    public void crearPDF(Integer idProyecto, Usuarios usuario, String email, Boolean archivoDoc, Locale locale) throws SQLException
    {
        System.err.println("Entrando en crearPDF");
        //String ruta = "\\\\SERVER\\producción\\PDFAPP\\" + usuario.getNombre() + "\\";
        String ruta = "/home/haritz/pdfapp/" + usuario.getNombre() + "/";
        Integer versionProyecto;

        File rutaFile = new File(ruta);

        JRPdfExporter exp = new JRPdfExporter();
        JRPdfExporter exp2 = new JRPdfExporter();
        JRDocxExporter expD = new JRDocxExporter();

        Connection conn = null;

        if(!rutaFile.exists()){
            rutaFile.mkdirs();
        }

        MailUtil mUtil = new MailUtil();

        String nombreProyecto;

        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

        //LOCALIZACIÓN DE INFORMES

        //Si no viene especificado por el administrador, extraer el idioma del contexto (establecido en función del usuario)
        if(locale == null){
            locale = context.getViewRoot().getLocale();
        }
        //Genera el ResourceBundle que le pasaremos por parámetro
        ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.appglass.jasper.resources.report", locale);

        //Introducimos los parámetros necesarios
        HashMap <String, Object> map = new HashMap <String, Object>();

        map.put("rutaImagenes", (Object) rutaImagenes);
        map.put("idProyecto", (Object) idProyecto);
        map.put("archivoDoc", (Object) archivoDoc);
        map.put(JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE,locale);
        map.put(JRParameter.REPORT_RESOURCE_BUNDLE, rb);

        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();

        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        try{


            //Nuevo para conseguir session.connection() en hibernate 4.x
            SessionFactoryImpl sessionFactory = (SessionFactoryImpl) session.getSessionFactory();
            conn = sessionFactory.getConnectionProvider().getConnection();
            //session.connection() fue borrado en hibernate 4.x
            //conn = session.connection();

/*JRProperties.setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.font.name", "Deja Vu Sans");

JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportSource);
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params);

JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, outputFileName);            */
            InputStream reporte = (InputStream) getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/appglass/jasper/report2.jasper");
            InputStream reporte2 = (InputStream) getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/appglass/jasper/report2_subreport1B.jasper");
            InputStream reporte3 = (InputStream) getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/appglass/jasper/report2_subreport2B.jasper");
            InputStream reporte4 = (InputStream) getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/appglass/jasper/report2_plano.jasper");
            InputStream reporte5 = (InputStream) getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/appglass/jasper/report2_resumen.jasper");
            // Path completo C:/Users/pool/Documents/NetBeansProjects/AppGlass/src/java

            if ((reporte == null) || reporte2 == null || reporte3 == null || reporte4 == null){
                System.err.println("No se ha encontrado el archivo .jasper");
            }

            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte, map, conn);
            System.err.println("Report1 done");
            JasperPrint jasperPrint2 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte2, map, conn); //THIS RISES AN ERROR
            JasperPrint jasperPrint3 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte3, map, conn);
            JasperPrint jasperPrint4 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte4, map, conn);
            JasperPrint jasperPrint5 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte5, map, conn);
            System.err.println("Antes de llamar a JasperViewer.viewReport");


            //Para exportar el PDF al cliente
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) context.getExternalContext().getResponse();


            List list = new ArrayList();
            list.add(jasperPrint4);
            list.add(jasperPrint5);
            list.add(jasperPrint);
            list.add(jasperPrint2);
            list.add(jasperPrint3);


            if(!archivoDoc){
                exp.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT_LIST, list);
                exp2.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT_LIST, list);
                exp.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.CHARACTER_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
                exp.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.CHARACTER_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
            }

            nombreProyecto = queryGetNombreProyecto(conn, idProyecto);


            versionProyecto = queryGetVersionProyecto(conn, idProyecto);

            if(!archivoDoc){
                //Fijamos como salida un fichero en SERVER
                exp2.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, ruta + nombreProyecto + "version" + (versionProyecto + 1) + ".pdf");
                exp2.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.METADATA_AUTHOR, usuario.getNombre());
                exp2.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.METADATA_TITLE, nombreProyecto);
                exp2.exportReport();
            } else {
                expD.setParameter(JRDocxExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT_LIST, list);
                //Fijamos como salida un fichero en SERVER
                expD.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, ruta + nombreProyecto + "(" + (versionProyecto + 1) + ").doc");

                //Fijamos como salida la un fichero en el servidor remoto
                expD.exportReport();
            }

            //Enviamos el mail de confirmación con el informe adjunto
            mUtil.confirmacionInforme(email, usuario, nombreProyecto, archivoDoc, versionProyecto + 1);

            //Fijamos como salida el lector de PDF del navegador
            if(!archivoDoc){

               response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf; charset=UTF-8");
               response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename*=UTF-8\'\'" + URLEncoder.encode(nombreProyecto, "UTF-8") + ".pdf");
               exp.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, response.getOutputStream());
               exp.exportReport();
            }


        }catch(SQLException sqlEx){
            System.err.println("Error creando el PDF");
            System.err.println(sqlEx.getClass());
            System.err.println(sqlEx.getCause());
            System.err.println(sqlEx.getMessage());

        }
        catch (HibernateException ex)
        {

            System.err.println("Error creando el PDF");
            System.err.println(ex.getClass());
            System.err.println(ex.getCause());
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());

        } catch (JRException ex) {
            System.err.println("Error creando el PDF");
            System.err.println(ex.getClass());
            System.err.println(ex.getCause());
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println("Error creando el PDF");
            System.err.println(ex.getClass());
            System.err.println(ex.getCause());
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
        } finally {

            if(conn != null){
                tx.commit();
                conn.close();
            }
        }
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
    }
}
```

ConstantesDAO.java

```
public Constantes cargarConstantes() throws IndexOutOfBoundsException
    {
        Constantes c = new Constantes();
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        try
        {
            c = (Constantes) session.createCriteria(Constantes.class).
                    add(Restrictions.eq("id", 1)).
                    list().get(0);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex)
        {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Problema al cargar las constantes de la base de datos. Espere unos minutos y vuelva a intentarlo.");
        } 
        return c;
```

UPDATE:
I've removed all pages of the PDF except one, i.e.:
This is not anymore

```
JasperPrint jasperPrint2 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte2, map, conn); //THIS RISES AN ERROR
JasperPrint jasperPrint3 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte3, map, conn);
JasperPrint jasperPrint4 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte4, map, conn);
JasperPrint jasperPrint5 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte5, map, conn);
```

Only this is in the code, and it works!

```
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte, map, conn);
```

but I need all pages, not just one.

Comment: Check here: `at com.appglass.data.dao.ConstantesDAO.cargarConstantes(ConstantesDAO.java:32) `

Comment: I've updated the question. ConstantesDAO line32 is this one:     session.beginTransaction(). Why is not beginTransaction done succesfully in the server but it can be done in localhost? Thank you!

Comment: Because your connection configuration is different? E.g. Localhost: autocommit="false", server: autocommit="true"?

Comment: Connection configuration to the DB is the same. In my PC I use Glassfish with Netbeans while in the server I use just glassfish. Is it possible that Netbeans makes Glassfish behaves in a different way? Thnx!

Comment: well, then jasper reports tries to create a new transaction each time. Maybe you should debug all that... I'm inclined to remove the jsf tag since it is not related to jsf at all.

Comment: What about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036005/myisam-engine-transaction-support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it. I still don't know why it didn't work before in the server while in localhost it did. Anyway, I've changed in Reportes.java crearPDF(...) this:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
```

by:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
```

and at the end of the function I've called session.close() in a finally block.