# InnoDB transaction and MyISAM example

Tags: mysql

InnoDB supports transaction and MyISAM does not support transaction.
I don't understand how it does and does not support transaction.Can anyone explain with example.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036005/myisam-engine-transaction-support

Comment: I want any example

Comment: An example of what, exactly? It's just a feature. With MyISAM, you cannot execute a transaction against the table. It will just ignore any rollback commands. And it will immediately save any DML statements, without waiting for a commit statement. The reason for that is due to how the table types are designed. Everything you need to know is already in the link which Julien posted, above. Did you read it??

Comment: S i saw the link

Comment: Ok. And now you have read it, is there something specific which you still don't understand? Please be clear about what you are really asking. Because according to your question above, the answer is already contained in that link.

Comment: S got it.Thank you