# Transaction across multiple Eloquent Models using Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, transactions

I want to insert a parent item and all of it's childs into a database. If any of the childs fails to create I'd like to abort the entire transaction.

I've tried using the following snippet:

```php
DB::beginTransaction();

try
{
    // Create parent item
    $one = new ModelOne();
    $one->key = 'Parent Key';
    $one->title = 'Parent title';
    $one->save();

    // Create child items
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $two = new ModelTwo();
        $two->parent_id = $one->id;
        $two->content = $item->content;
        $two->status = $item->status;
        $two->save();
    }

    DB::commit();
    return response(['message'=>'ALL GOOD'], 200);
}
catch (\ Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e)
{
    DB::rollBack();
    return response(['message'=>'FAILURE'], 500);
}
```

However, when an exception is thrown (say because a key is duplicated among the childs) `ModelOne` (`$one`) is saved in the database even though `DB::commit()` is never called.

What am I missing?

I'm using Laravel 5.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue has nothing to do with the code I provided in the question.

The problem was that my tables were being created using `MyISAM` which [does not support transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8036049/5686352).

Using `InnoDB` instead makes the code work as expected. To do so add `$table->engine = 'InnoDB';` to your migrations.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code for transactions and it works:

```
DB::transaction(function () { 
});
```

With this code you do not need to commit or rollback. They are called automatically.

In your case you will have:

```
try {
    DB::transaction(function () use ($items) ({ 
        // ... your inserts
    });
catch () {}
```

Comment: Using DB::transaction produces the same result, ModelOne is inserted even if the creation of a ModelTwo fails

Comment: Check if your configuration supports the transactions